# PHPUnit can't find my Silex routes

Tags: php, phpunit, silex

I code a Silex application which works great, now i would like to write some functionnal tests with PHPUnit.
I write a PHP class like:

```
 <?php
 namespace foo\Tests;

 require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

 use Silex\WebTestCase;
 use Silex\Application;

class WebAppTreeTest extends WebTestCase
{
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = new Application();
    return $app;
}

public function test404()
{
    $client = $this->createClient();
    $client->request('GET', '/give-me-a-404');
    $this->assertEquals(404, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}

public function testGet()
{
    $client = $this->createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/id/123545');

    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isOk());
    $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('Created'));
}
}
```

I tried to run the test with `phpunit` but it returns one failure, the second test fail. After debugging a bit i found that PHPUnit can't get the route…
That route is reachable from my broswer tho.

Any tips ?

**EDIT:**

My phpunit.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"  
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    stopOnError="false"
    stopOnIncomplete="false"
    stopOnSkipped="false"
    syntaxCheck="false"
    bootstrap="app/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="FormOptimizer Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules? Try to enable debugging to get more info.

Comment: Provide your phpunit configuration file etc - [example](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/testing.html#configuration)

Comment: @Neok See the edit. Alex: how can i see the entire url PHPunit is using ? I tried with and without rewrite rules, same same

Answer (score 4):

Your method `createApplication` returns bare application `$app = new Application(); return $app;` without routes and etc.
Try to initialize `app` as it is initialized in `app/bootstrap.php` or return `app` from globals.

```
public function createApplication()
{
    return $_GLOBALS['app'];
}
```